# how will be the hashcode calculated for objects created for collection data types in java?

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

From recent studies, my understanding is that **hashCode** is a method which returns unique integer for an object instantiated for a certain datatype. But calculating hashcode for all the datatype objects will use same algorithm or will it vary according to some logic? I didn't get much information about the hashcode calculation mechanism specifically for **collection datatypes**. If any clarifications or references will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, here is how `AbstractList` calculates it's hashCode;

```
/**
 * Returns the hash code value for this list.
 *
 * <p>This implementation uses exactly the code that is used to define the
 * list hash function in the documentation for the {@link List#hashCode}
 * method.
 *
 * @return the hash code value for this list
 */
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```

Also, hashcode is not necessarily unique.

Comment: No need to look at the code - it's in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--)

Comment: @Qwerky this is worst example of hashCode. hashCode is used to put elements in a Map as keys. A list that is variable during time doesn't follow the general contract, particulary: "Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer"

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO - Don't blame me, its core java code. Also you missed a bit in your quote, probably the important bit `provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified`. If two lists are equal and you change one of the lists, they are no longer equal, so they should have different hashcodes.

Comment: @Qwerky the problem is not that we didn't talk about equals (you are right also equals must be well written), but a List can't be used as a key in a Map because it changes its hashCode when changing its content. So is not a good example. Probably the use of it is for immodificable lists,

Comment: @Querky if you use a list in a map as a key. And you change the content of the list. You can't retrieve the original object using that key. Any object that change the value of its hashCode during his life can't be used in a map as key!

Comment: @Quertky I show you a simple code in my answer to explain why a List can't be used as a key. It doesn't follow the contract.

Comment: @Querty Your comment and Andreas comment on my answer opened my eyes. I wrong translated that part from english to my language. So I tried to translate it better and I saw my error. I excuse me to pointed as an error what an error was not. I updated my answer with the note of Josh Block and  Brian Goetz explaining why a List should not be used as a key. **But a List hashCode follow the  contract!** You are right

Answer (score -1):

Calculating the `hashCode` depends on the class. There is no standard rule.

You need only to follow the rules explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> The general contract of `hashCode` is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

---

This part of the answer is to explain a comment on the answer of Qwerky, sorry but is not easy to show a complete fragment of code on comments.

Here a simple code explaining why **a `List` can't be used as a key in the map**.

```
    Map<List, String> map = new HashMap<List, String>();
    List list = new ArrayList();
    map.put(list, "a");
    System.out.println("Before: " + map.get(list)); // Print A
    list.add(new Object());
    System.out.println("After: " + map.get(list)); // Print null
```

**Note that the List follow the contract of `hashCode`.**

**But** as it been noted by Brian Goetz and Josh Bloch that:

> If an object’s `hashCode()` value can change based on its state, then we must be careful when using such objects as keys in hash-based collections to ensure that we don’t allow their state to change when they are being used as hash keys. **All hash-based collections assume that an object’s hash value does not change while it is in use as a key** in the collection. **If a key’s hash code were to change** while it was in a collection, **some unpredictable and confusing consequences could follow**. This is usually not a problem in practice — **it is not common practice to use a mutable object like a List as a key in a HashMap**.

Comment: Please comment downvotes to show what is wrong in the answer.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but a list can be used as key, same as any other object. The requirement that keys must be immutable with regards to `hashCode()` and `equals()` *(for `HashMap`)*, and `compareTo()` *(for `TreeMap()`)* applies to *all* kinds of keys, not just lists. *Any* object used as a key must not be updated *while* the object is a key. --- Also, the question is not about maps at all, so why even talk about the restrictions of map keys?

Comment: hashCode is not a standard function. The purpose of hashCode is strictly connected to HashMaps. There is an explicit contract that all object must follow, and lists doesn't follow it. The explicit reference to Lists has been done to complete a comment on the answer ot Qwerky

Comment: @Andreas I added the explicit reference to the answer of Qwerty to be more clear. Thanks for your comment

Comment: What contract are you referring to? Are you referring to the [section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) *"Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects `equals` comparisons while the object is a key in the map."* If so, then `List` is just one of many types of *mutable* objects, where great care must be exercised, i.e. they can be used as keys as long as they are not mutated while being a key. Still, **`List` is allowed to be a key**.

Comment: The original question is about "hashcode calculation mechanism", not about the mutable state of the object, so your entire rant about `List` is way off point. Your comment about "[worst example of hashCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226969/38227092?noredirect=1#comment63876138_38227101)" to another question is also wrong, because that was a very valid `hashCode()` implementation. Hash codes are supposed to change when the object is mutated, otherwise it wouldn't be consistent with equals, as it is required to be.

Comment: @Andreas no, hashCode MUST follow the general contract. See it on the javadoc of Object. Reported also in my answer. If hashCode doesn't follow the general contract becomes a not useful function because its only purpose is to find the bucket where the key will be added in the HashMap. Writing an hashCode that follow only the second rule of the contract is same of writing a function that doesn't follow the contract. Infact as you can see in the example using it in a Map you can lost your data.

Comment: Which part of the contract does `List` not follow? It follows all 3 rules, without fail. As was already commented to you, the first rules says *"hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, **provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified**"*. `List` fully complies with that rule, i.e. the hash code stays unchanged, as long as the list or any of its elements are not changed. Your code example loses data because *you* violated the rule, not `List`. *You* changed the list. That is not the fault of `List`, which did everything correct, by the rules.

Comment: @Andreas thank you Andreas. I wrong translated that part in my language, so I didn't understood well that part of the contract. I update my answer now that your comment pointed it and I tried to better translate it.

Answer (score -1):

Hi the default hashcode method returns the object reference as classname@Soome numeric value which is unique, but in case of collection we override the hashcode method to generate our custom key, at the same time we override the equals method to get the correct output.

you can get details idea from my code below

```
package com.rk.collections;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private int regdno;
    private String city;
   private  String college;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getRegdno() {
    return regdno;
}
public void setRegdno(int regdno) {
    this.regdno = regdno;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getCollege() {
    return college;
}
public void setCollege(String college) {
    this.college = college;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {


    return regdno;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;


    if (regdno != other.regdno)


    return false;
    return true;
}


public String toString() {
    return "Employee [name=" + name + ", regdno=" + regdno + ", city=" + city + ", college=" + college + "]";
}



}

public class MapDemo {
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
     Employee e1=new Employee();
     e1.setName("Amlan");
     e1.setRegdno(326);
     e1.setCity("Bhanjanagar");
     e1.setCollege("IGIT");

     Employee e2=new Employee();
     e2.setName("Amlan");
     e2.setRegdno(325);
     e2.setCity("Sambalpur");
     e2.setCollege("IGIT");

     Employee e3=new Employee();
     e3.setName("Tapas");
     e3.setRegdno(324);
     e3.setCity("Baripada");
     e3.setCollege("IGIT");

     HashMap<Employee,Employee> hs=new HashMap();
     hs.put(e1,e1);
     hs.put(e2,e2);
     hs.put(e3,e3);
     System.out.println(hs.size());
     for(Map.Entry m:hs.entrySet())
     {
         System.out.println(m.getValue());
     }

 }



}
```